# Heroku deployment failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have this rails site I want to deploy but not used to heroku, and I am not able to undertsand this heroku logs:

➜       LisbonExperienceRails git:(master) ✗ heroku logs --tail
         2020-03-29T18:24:22.842298+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.3- 
         p62), codename: Mysterious Traveller
`enter code here`              2020-03-29T18:24:22.842299+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min `enter code here`threads: 5, max threads: 5
`enter code here`2`enter code here`020-03-29T18:24:22.842323+00:00 app[web.1]: * `enter code here`
`enter code here`Environment: production
`enter code here`2020-03-29T18:24:24.389690+00:00 heroku[run.1436]: State changed

```
from starting to up
2020-03-29T18:24:24.790160+00:00 heroku[run.1436]: Awaiting client
2020-03-29T18:24:24.840400+00:00 heroku[run.1436]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate`
2020-03-29T18:24:30.040224+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:18470
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042395+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma)
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042479+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/server.pid
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042482+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `initialize'
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042482+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `open'
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042483+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `write_pid'
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042483+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:105:in `write_state'
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042484+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/single.rb:103:in `run'
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042484+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042485+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in `run'
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042485+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042487+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2020-03-29T18:24:30.042487+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
2020-03-29T18:24:30.144051+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-29T18:24:30.128568+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-03-29T18:24:32.875605+00:00 heroku[run.1436]: State changed from up to complete
2020-03-29T18:24:32.858184+00:00 heroku[run.1436]: Process exited with status 0
2020-03-29T18:25:08.039240+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=c7c63b60-be70-4c82-aa40-f4b8c1045dab fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:25:08.964216+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=87dc4beb-f129-45a8-86f5-0914252675cd fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:34:55.211912+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=8cfb30b5-e9ab-4e8a-b9db-6382002556f5 fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:34:55.911037+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=668543c5-164f-40f3-afc3-82e280d19b50 fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:37:06.279698+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=c1eb428f-a1ba-461c-9126-5a7bbbf6915e fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:37:07.431538+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=0cf9b521-2ff6-4600-ae25-a4ba23036e13 fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:40:00.086892+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=8c29310f-5f06-4c65-87a1-5c2451ff2c75 fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:40:00.856712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=f6e7ab71-b607-4a4f-8e89-b9e740b1b3ea fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:44:00.103996+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake -T` by user cecile_rougnaux@hotmail.com
2020-03-29T18:44:10.066646+00:00 heroku[run.8343]: State changed from starting to up
2020-03-29T18:44:10.780483+00:00 heroku[run.8343]: Awaiting client
2020-03-29T18:44:10.845048+00:00 heroku[run.8343]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake -T`
2020-03-29T18:44:18.078898+00:00 heroku[run.8343]: State changed from up to complete
2020-03-29T18:44:18.059294+00:00 heroku[run.8343]: Process exited with status 0
2020-03-29T18:44:54.949571+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake -T` by user cecile_rougnaux@hotmail.com
2020-03-29T18:45:03.226651+00:00 heroku[run.1199]: State changed from starting to up
2020-03-29T18:45:03.443510+00:00 heroku[run.1199]: Awaiting client
2020-03-29T18:45:03.500283+00:00 heroku[run.1199]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake -T`
2020-03-29T18:45:10.169424+00:00 heroku[run.1199]: State changed from up to complete
2020-03-29T18:45:10.153328+00:00 heroku[run.1199]: Process exited with status 0
2020-03-29T18:45:35.142130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=9349fc3a-c140-4a1c-b54b-0d10474ad670 fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:45:36.051022+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=56be90fa-da28-4455-9de0-478487d70bc4 fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:48:40.207301+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle install` by user cecile_rougnaux@hotmail.com
2020-03-29T18:48:48.384063+00:00 heroku[run.1409]: State changed from starting to up
2020-03-29T18:48:53.268671+00:00 heroku[run.1409]: State changed from up to complete
2020-03-29T18:48:54.350707+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user cecile_rougnaux@hotmail.com
2020-03-29T18:49:01.631020+00:00 heroku[run.1442]: State changed from starting to up
2020-03-29T18:49:01.752331+00:00 heroku[run.1442]: Awaiting client
2020-03-29T18:49:01.807471+00:00 heroku[run.1442]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2020-03-29T18:49:08.730528+00:00 heroku[run.1442]: State changed from up to complete
2020-03-29T18:49:08.714537+00:00 heroku[run.1442]: Process exited with status 0
2020-03-29T18:50:20.441131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-03-29T18:50:27.885259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2020-03-29T18:50:30.518292+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2020-03-29T18:50:30.518326+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2020-03-29T18:50:30.518327+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2020-03-29T18:50:30.518327+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2020-03-29T18:50:34.228872+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:45195
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229460+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma)
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229526+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/server.pid
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229528+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `initialize'
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229529+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `open'
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229529+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `write_pid'
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229529+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:105:in `write_state'
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229530+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/single.rb:103:in `run'
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229530+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229531+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in `run'
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229531+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229532+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2020-03-29T18:50:34.229533+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
2020-03-29T18:50:34.305375+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-29T18:50:34.287584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-03-29T18:51:10.041481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-03-29T18:51:09.701111+00:00 app[api]: Set GMAIL_EMAIL, GMAIL_PASSWORD config vars by user cecile_rougnaux@hotmail.com
2020-03-29T18:51:09.701111+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user cecile_rougnaux@hotmail.com
2020-03-29T18:51:18.393405+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2020-03-29T18:51:21.735395+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2020-03-29T18:51:21.735421+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2020-03-29T18:51:21.735430+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2020-03-29T18:51:21.735431+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2020-03-29T18:51:26.103643+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:44574
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104208+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma)
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104286+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/server.pid
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104287+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `initialize'
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104287+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `open'
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104288+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `write_pid'
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104288+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:105:in `write_state'
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104288+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/single.rb:103:in `run'
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104289+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104289+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in `run'
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104289+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.3/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104290+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2020-03-29T18:51:26.104290+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
2020-03-29T18:51:26.209443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-29T18:51:26.188677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-03-29T18:51:35.536923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=df9ff8aa-78d4-44d2-a570-ac2132eee46b fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-29T18:51:36.280816+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen-scrubland-52032.herokuapp.com request_id=d9680377-a55e-4aa7-9194-6b167a88311a fwd="79.168.11.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Thanks for your help, any ;))
C

Answer (score 0):

Raily should automatically create those folders during initialization via `bundle exec rails server`.

Since you're executing puma diretctly, those folders don't exist yet. To fix that you should either launch your server with the recommended command above, or use a script to create the `tmp` and `tmp/pids` directories before running the exec command.